# How to get test predictions after cross validation

Tags: python, scikit-learn

My code-

I have split my code in this manner-

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_array, y_labels, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)
```

Now I do cross-validation to see the performance of my trained model-

```
scoring = 'accuracy'
val_acc_results = cross_val_score(rf,X_train,y_train, cv=10, scoring=scoring)
```

This will give me the accuracy of the trained set. How do I evaluate my learnt model on my test dataset now? SInce cross_val_score is not returning an model object?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the estimator on full training data, [`cross_val_score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html) only returns the score. You now do:

```
rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
predictions = rf.predict(X_test)
```

Then to get the accuracy on test data, do:

```
from sklearn import metrics
metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, predictions)
```

Comment: Whats the use of doing cross validation then if I have to run the estimator on the full training data?

Comment: To see how well the model is doing on different samples (folds) of data to ensure the data distribution is similar in each fold and model performance is stable.